# ReCaptcha V2 Force Text Validation

Tags: recaptcha

With ReCaptcha V2, is it at all possible to force Text Validation when the simple "checkbox" validation fails?

One of our products uses ReCaptcha V2, however one of our clients in Vietnam is uneasy about this, since they seem to get a high percentage of clicks that require image validation, and they think their users won't understand how to do the validation...